# Excel formula based on If logic

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to build a formula if the value is 15% then 0 to 5% * 2, 5% to 10% * 5, 10% to 15% * 10  and sum of the value needs to be shown as a result.

Comment: Can you clear up your question a bit, its hard to see what you are asking.

Comment: Use regex its a best solution

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following logic - 
*If value >= 15% then return 0 

If value < 5% then return value * 2 

If value is >= 5% and < 10% then return value * 5 

If value is between >= 10% and < 15% then return value * 10*

You could try -
`=IF((percentage) >= 0.15, actualValue * 0,
IF((percentage) < 0.05, actualValue * 2,
IF(AND((percentage) >= 0.05, (percentage) < 0.1), actualValue * 5,
IF(AND(((percentage) >= 0.1), ((percentage) < 0.15)), actualValue * 10))))`